# How is image caching implemented in android - volley?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

From what I understand we need to provide the implementation of `LRU cache` and pass the same as constructor to the image loader.

There is also a default disk based cache present in `volley`. This disk based cache is used for caching `HTTP` responses.

**Which cache  will be used  when the image downloaded contains cache headers ??

1. LRU(own implementation)
2. Default disc cache implementation present inside volley toolbox package**strong text** **  to
   public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache implements ImageLoader.ImageCache

{

```
public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    return cacheSize;
}

public BitmapLruCache() {
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
}

public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url, bitmap);
}}
```

This is the call which is used to set the Image in the network view

```
ImageLoader mImageLoader = new          ImageLoader(ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue(), new BitmapLruCache());
 holder.imageicon.setImageUrl(i.getThumb_image(), mImageLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LRU cache is used for caching the images.  See the source code for [ImageLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java) - uses an `ImageCache`, which is an interface volley provides you to implement in your extended `LruCache`.  So, your cache would both extend `LruCache<String,Bitmap>` and implement an `ImageCache`.

The default cache that volley provides is used to every response it gets, with the default strat of caching according to cache headers of the HTTP response.  So, if they have the right cache headers, they'll be cached on disk, if they don't, they won't.

So, to answer your question in full, potentially both caches will be used -- but as far as retrieving the images go, the in memory cache (or your lru cache) will be used.

Comment: I got that part ..which cache will be used when image url contains caching headers ??

Comment: If you look at the source code I linked - you'll see that the ImageCache is used from within the ImageLoader class - which as I already said, is your implementation of your LruCache.  If there's a miss in your LruCache, the HTTP request will go off as expected, and then it'll check the HTTP cache, then if theres a miss there, go to the network.

Comment: ok thank you got it ...But in my case there is no cache hit present inside my  LRU cache ...All the images are displayed from the disc based cache ...Do u have any idea when it happens ??I have edited my post to include the source code of LRU implementation

Comment: Are you creating a new cache for each ImageLoader instance?  That's probably why you're not getting hits as expected.

Comment: I normally set up a CacheManager class, and initialize a single instance of the ImageLoader and ImageCache when my application starts, and then just access them through a static singleton.  From the looks of your last two lines of code, you're creating a new cache for each imageloader you create.